# Meromorphic algebraic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Is it rue that an algebraic meromorphic function is algebraic over $\mathbb C(z)$ if and only it belongs to $\mathbb C(z)$?

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

$f$ satisfies $p(z,f(z))=0$, and let's for convenience assume that $p$ is irreducible (but the argument works in general). We have two meromorphic maps on the associated Riemann surface $R=\{ (z,w): p(z,w)=0\}$: the standard map $(z,w)\mapsto w$ and also $(z,w)\mapsto f(z)$, this being the composition of $(z,w)\mapsto z$ with $f$.

These maps agree on an open subset of $R$, so are identical. It follows that $p$ is of degree one in $w$, so $f$ is rational.

Comment: Thanks for this very helpful answer.